# Putting CSV file in MYSQL database doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm working for school on a website where I need to upload a `csv`file in a `mysql` database with `php`.
I cannot simply upload it on phpMyAdmin.

Now i'm working on some code to do this for me. But the code is not getting it done to put my CSV file into `mysql` database. I have read several other questions from people but the answers there are not helping me

I have 2 files one is

`connection.php`

```
$dbName = "i296297_studie";
$user = "username";
$password = "password";
$host = "localhost";

$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbName);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

That is working fine and one is
 `test1.php`

```
include "connection.php"; //connectie database
$deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE olympischespelen"; //haalt de tabel leeg
mysqli_query($connection, $deleterecords);


//wanneer file is geupload 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $csv_file = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
    if (($getfile = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) { 
        $data = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ";");
        while (($data = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
         $num = count($data); 
         for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
             $result = $data; 
             $str = implode(";", $result); 
             $slice = explode(";", $str);
             $col1 = $slice[0]; 
             $col2 = $slice[1];
             $col3 = $slice[2];
             $col4 = $slice[3];
             $col5 = $slice[4];
             $col6 = $slice[5];

// SQL Query to insert data into DataBase

$query = "INSERT INTO `i296297_studie`.`olympischespelen` (`sport`, `deelnemers`, `goud`, `zilver`, `brons`, `totaal`) 
VALUES ('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."','".$col4."','".$col5."','".$col6."')";

        mysqli_query($query, $connection); 
     }
   } 
  }

echo "File data successfully imported to database!!"; 
mysqli_close($connect); 

}else {

    print "Upload new csv by browsing to file and clicking on Upload<br />\n";
    print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='test1.php' method='post'>";
    print "File name to import:<br />\n";
    print "<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";
    print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'></form>";

}

?>
```

But I don't know where it is getting wrong. When I echo `$col1` or the others they are outputting the data I wanted.

Hope you could help me Thanks

Comment: What **exactly** wrong? Aliens stole your computer? You get blank screen? You get something else?

Comment: You are mixing mysql and mysqli functions. Is this a typo?

Comment: It is not putting my csv in my database.

Comment: @lolka_bolka I'm working with mysqli and I changed the query but still it is not able to put my content in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the connection link as the first argument

```
mysqli_query($query, $connection);
```

should be

```
mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php  

//connect to the database 
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password"); 
mysql_select_db("mydatabase",$connect); //select the table 
// 

if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts (contact_first, contact_last, contact_email) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."' 
                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 
    // 

    //redirect 
    header('Location: import.php?success=1'); die; 

} 

?>

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
<title>Import a CSV File with PHP & MySQL</title> 
</head> 

<body> 

<?php if (!empty($_GET[success])) { echo "<b>Your file has been imported.</b><br><br>"; } //generic success notice ?> 

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
  Choose your file: <br /> 
  <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" /> 
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form> 

</body> 
</html>
```

See, if that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You call this `fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ";");` two times.

**Try this**

```
if (($getfile = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) { 
        while (($data = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data); 
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                $result = $data; 
                $str = implode(";", $result); 
                $slice = explode(";", $str);
                $col1 = $slice[0]; 
                $col2 = $slice[1];
                $col3 = $slice[2];
                $col4 = $slice[3];
                $col5 = $slice[4];
                $col6 = $slice[5];

                // SQL Query to insert data into DataBase

                $query = "INSERT INTO `i296297_studie`.`olympischespelen` (`sport`, `deelnemers`, `goud`, `zilver`, `brons`, `totaal`) 
                VALUES ('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."','".$col4."','".$col5."','".$col6."')";

                mysqli_query($query, $connection); 
            }
        } 
    }
```

And all data filter by `mysql_real_escape_string` function before insert into db..